# Customizing Sphinx search results

Tags: sphinx

I can see the template for search results https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/search.html (sphinx_rtd_theme).

I'd like to change the table result to have more info. Specifically more about the path. I think I am supposed to have a modified copy of that file in my `_templates` directory and have `{%- extends "sphinx_rtd_theme/search.html" %}` at the top to get it to activate. It isn't picking that up though after a full rebuild.  What am I misunderstanding?